# Share form-input on twitter

Tags: php, javascript, forms, twitter, field

I want to use the share-link-technology of twitter to publish stuff people enter into a form on twitter. Like this

1. Person enters "www.mywebsite.com" into a field
2. Person clicks on a button called "share"
3. This opens twitter.com and fills into the tweet-field "this is my website: www.mywebsite.com"

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Link

On Button click call this link with predefined status="this is my website: www.mywebsite.com"

> [http://twitter.com/home?status="this is my website:
>   www.mywebsite.com"](http://twitter.com/home?status=%22this%20is%20my%20website%3a%20www.mywebsite.com%22)

For more Reference

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

Comment: Ok thank you! How do I get the stuff the person entered into the field into this?

Comment: you can post it but can't retrieve

Comment: why you need to retrieve that message ?

Comment: Ah I found a way to do this: <form action="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=" method="get">
<input type="text" name="text" />
<input type="submit" value="share!" />
</form>

Comment: But now I need to add this "my work:" text before the filled in domain. Any ideas?

Comment: on your website user will write the message or you will post a predefined message ?

Comment: combination of both! like this: "my work: [entered information]"